# What is Difference Between Group,Bundle,Configurable,Virtual & Simple Product In Magento?

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, product, magento2.3

I can't Find the difference between in all of them.Please Explain it.

Comment: Here Magento Official Document and easily you have understand 
https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-types.html

Answer (score 3):

What are the differences between product types in Magento ?
Ans => I have explain you differences for compare product type. If you not aware about product type so please first [read](https://www.customerparadigm.com/six-types-of-magento-product-types/) it.

1. Simple Products
2. Grouped Products
3. Configurable Products
4. Virtual Products
5. Bundled Products
6. Downloadable Products

**Simple vs. Configurable**

**Simple products** are the most frequently used product on a Magento store. A Simple Product is a basic product, with no options for the customer to choose and one price.

**Configurable product**.This type of goods is used for single item with specific selectable variations to choose. This kind of Magento product types is usually used for clothing, which as a rule is customized by selecting size, color, material etc.

**Grouped vs Bundled**

**Grouped Products** are a group of Simple, stand-alone products that have been grouped together. The group of products can only be offered at their normal fixed price (as if they were being offered as a simple, standalone product).

**Bundled Product** .Using it you can also sell product as a kit, but contrary to grouped product, you cannot skip any of its components. Products belonging to it cannot be sold separately and you can only select which exactly options from offered you prefer. Think about a laptop where the customer can choose various monitors, processors, memory etc.

**Downloadable vs. Virtual**

**Downloadable Product** This product has downloadable counterpart. Think about an MP3 file, Magento extension or similar. Downloadable product does not allow selecting a shipping method at checkout, simply because shipping is not needed and client receives purchased entity right away.

**Virtual product** These Magento products are not physical or digital entries. They cannot be shipped or downloaded from the link. This is a great way to sell services or intellectual products such as warranties, subscription or updates.

Getting *[Reference](https://www.customerparadigm.com/different-product-types/)* [Reference2](https://www.mag-manager.com/useful-articles/how-to-create-different-types-of-products-in-magento/)

Answer (score 1):

> **there are 6 Magento product types available. Those are:**

1. Simple Products
2. Grouped Products
3. Configurable Products
4. Virtual Products
5. Bundled Products
6. Downloadable Products

**1) Simple Products**

> **As you can guess from its name, it is a physical good that is sold at the store. This one is the most common among all Magento product
>   types. Simple product is recommended to be used for a single unit with
>   no special selectable options. Every item has own SKU (Stock Keeping
>   Unit), price, and inventory. In case you wish, as an admin, you may
>   add desired options with an input price, color, size, or else for the
>   customer’s choice. Even the basic goods have more chances to be sold
>   when you involve some choice.**

```
Examples: a glass, a soft toy, a DVD, camera lens, some office supplies or inventory.
```

**2) Configurable (a.k.a. Complex) Products**

> **Now this one is far more complicated. Usually, this Magento product type is associated with clothing as far it is the best example. Since
>   clothes are sold in various sizes, shapes, and colors, users wish to
>   “configure” their choices before purchasing. Configurable product is
>   the one made of several simple products. To understand better, pretend
>   you are selling a T-shirt that comes in S, M, and L sizes. You should
>   then develop a simple product for each size. Besides, the colors also
>   differ. You will come up with just as many products as there are
>   different sizes, shapes, and colors. Create a configurable product for
>   the catalog first. Then, under the associated products, an admin picks
>   all the created products for every of the sizes and color. Such
>   configuration creates a drop down menu for all specific clothing
>   features. Customers can easily select the product’s size, color, and
>   any other attributes to satisfy your needs in full. If you wish, you
>   can put a separate price for each option. In addition, you can put
>   inventory levels for every simple product with the different images of
>   your preference. Then, in case the inventory level of the small, blue
>   t-shirt is out of stock, then that option isn’t available (depending
>   on your settings). Product’s stock, price, and other characteristics
>   are monitored on the simple level with configurable product accounting
>   for the initial price. Often, Magento configurable products are known
>   as parent products while corresponding simple products are called
>   child.**

```
Examples: dress with different colors and sizes available, snickers with different sizes available, flashdrive with different volume etc.
```

**3) Grouped Products**

> **This one refers to the set of simple products. Usually, those are goods with the same features, related to each other. This type is the
>   best for promotional goals. Magento grouped products comes in handy
>   with the items that accomplish them (like accessories). It means that
>   instead of buying a memory card, USB, and a device, a customer will
>   get all three by making a single purchase which is very convenient.
>   Besides, often such goods come at a special price. It would be useful
>   whenever you decide to catch an eye of potential customers with vivid
>   promotion campaigns.**

```
Examples: camera lens + mini SD card + a digital camera itself, a smartphone with stylish case and wireless charger, Magento Red Furniture set featuring Ottoman, Chair, and Couch.
```

**4) Bundle Products**

> **Magento bundle product makes it possible for the customers to construct product they desire. This type is applied for a bundle of
>   simple or virtual goods that cannot be sold separately because it
>   makes no sense. Is there a reason to purchase laptop without a hard
>   disc, processor, and internal memory? That’s the point. Often, this
>   type is confused with the previous one, but, unlike grouped product,
>   bundle one provides the end user with the choice: they can combine any
>   products they want (color, size, memory, capacity, etc.). You can
>   assign inventory to every individual item. It is possible to make them
>   visible, so that someone could purchase extra cards as well. In
>   addition, buying all offered items together saves a plenty of money.**

```
Examples: camera body for $500 + lens that can be selected from: no lens at all, a basic lens for $200, or professional lens for $500 + memory card with options: no memory card at all, 8 GB card for $20, a 16 GB card for $32, and a 32 GB card for $52.
```

**5) Downloadable Products (also a simple one)**

> **You have to upload files via the back-end to the server through the admin or FTP before offering downloadable product. Input its price (if
>   any) and other additional information. There is an opportunity of
>   hosting the files on another web server. It’s up to Magento then to
>   provide a secure, encrypted personalized link to every customer. Mind
>   that this type of Magento product may consist of one or more
>   downloadable files, so you have the option to require all of them to
>   be purchased. No shipping options are offered as far as there is
>   nothing to be shipped. It’s up to you to decide whether your customer
>   will be able to choose the files to be included in the purchase. After
>   the link is generated, the customer is then capable of accessing all
>   the downloadable files purchased from the account’s corresponding
>   section. But in this case you risk your file will be stored and shared
>   with someone else. Anyway, Magento does not cover digital rights
>   management.**

```
Examples: some Magento extensions, applications, games, software, music files, E-books, etc.
```

**6) Virtual Products**

> **Magento virtual product was developed for those goods that do not need to be shipped, downloaded or delivered at all. These products are
>   known as intangible goods; they also do not need any stock
>   management.**

```
Examples: online consulting or support services, online language courses, technical service, insurance, reservation.
```